# Treating null field as zero for an update query

Tags: sql-server-express, increment, dbnull, query-builder

I'm using the SQL Express 2010 query builder.  I need to be able to increment a field.

In my behind code, I make a call such as

```
tableAdapter.IncrementLikeCount(id);
```

If I just use an increment, the like field can be null, so I want to either 
a. treat the null as zero in that field OR
b. set to 1, if null, and increment otherwise.

The most current thing I tried is option b with the following code in the query builder:

```
UPDATE       [dbo].[myTable]
SET                [LikeCount] = IIF(ISNULL([LikeCount]), 1, LikeCount + 1)
WHERE        ([ID] = @Original_ID)
```

However, this does not work.   The query builder keeps rewriting the expression inside the ISNULL without the square brackets and with a comma, as the following:

```
UPDATE       [dbo].[myTable]
SET                [LikeCount] = IIF(ISNULL(LikeCount,), 1, LikeCount + 1)
WHERE        ([ID] = @Original_ID)
```

Is there a clean, simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ISNULL statement needs a default to fall back to, like

```
ISNULL(LikeCount, 0)
```

where the 0 is the value that LikeCount becomes IF in fact it is null.

So, try

```
UPDATE       [dbo].[myTable]
SET          [LikeCount] = (ISNULL(LikeCount, 0) + 1)
WHERE        ([ID] = @Original_ID)
```

**UPDATE**

As to the query you posted in your comment:

```
UPDATE Documents 
SET docLikeCount = ISNULL(docLikeCount, 0) + 1
WHERE docID = @Original_docID
```

Comment: I tried:
UPDATE       Documents
SET                docLikeCount = IIF(ISNULL(docLikeCount, 0), 0, docLikeCount + 1) WHERE        (docID = @Original_docID)
.... and also as ...UPDATE       Documents
SET                docLikeCount = ISNULL(docLikeCount, 1, docLikeCount + 1)

WHERE        (docID = @Original_docID) 
... still getting syntax error.