# how to increment integer Columns value by 1 in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

For example, suppose a column `ID` has values 1,2,3,4, ...

Now when I `update` this table, the `ID` column should increment by 1,

Now `ID` will become 2,3,4,5, ...

How do you increment a column's value by 1 on `UPDATE`?

Comment: any sample about you want ? increment column's value by 1  for 1 row ? all rows ? which is your table (DDL) ? data samples (DML) ?

Answer (score 250):

To add one to every value in the table...

```
UPDATE myTable
SET ID = ID + 1
```

To create a new value, one more then the previous highest (usually),  use a [column with IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Comment: Please note that this does _not_ work when the column is NULL. NULL columns stay NULL, even after incrementing. For this to solve, use the [`ISNULL` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) like this: `UPDATE myTable SET ID = ISNULL(ID, 0) + 1` (Taken from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9136574/107625))

Comment: `SET [Lic] = [Lic] + @dif` . Note ***@dif*** variable can be _positive, 0, or negative_

Comment: This method  produces the following error: **"SQL error: UNIQUE constraint failed: {table}.id"**. All fields can be changed except 'id'. It's a known issue. I really wonder how this could be the selected solution ...

Answer (score 60):

If you want to have an unique number for each row automatically generated, this is IDENTITY as per Neil's answer.

If each time you update the table you want to increase the values (ie they are not keys):

```
Update MyTable
Set IDColumn = IDColumn + 1
Where <whatever>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
Update Emp set testCount = ISNULL(testCount, 0) + 1 where testId=1
```

Answer (score 8):

Update on the accepted answer

Might be shorter having it like this.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET ID += 1
WHERE <Condition>
```

Answer (score 4):

For postgresSQL

```
UPDATE myTable SET ID = COALESCE(id, 0) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) which will do this for you.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [MyTableID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    -- Other columns
)
```

When you insert your first record, you'll get an `Id` of 1.

Comment: The question is about updating a column in an existing row, not about incrementing an ID when inserting new rows.

Comment: But @Barmar it is a good observation worth raising with OP, it looks like using `IDENTITY` might have solved this problem in a different way in the first place, given that OPs number might be the reverse of the incrementing identity.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = @@ROWCOUNT + 1

INSERT INTO YourTable
        (Identity Column)    
VALUES    
        (@i + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle the code is a little bit more tricky.

You will have to create an auto-increment field with the sequence object (this object generates a number sequence).

Use the following CREATE SEQUENCE syntax:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10
```

The code above creates a sequence object called seq_person, that starts with 1 and will increment by 1. It will also cache up to 10 values for performance. The cache option specifies how many sequence values will be stored in memory for faster access.

To insert a new record into the "Persons" table, we will have to use the nextval function (this function retrieves the next value from seq_person sequence):

```
INSERT INTO Persons (ID,FirstName,LastName)
VALUES (seq_person.nextval,'Lars','Monsen')
```

The SQL statement above would insert a new record into the "Persons" table. The "ID" column would be assigned the next number from the seq_person sequence. The "FirstName" column would be set to "Lars" and the "LastName" column would be set to "Monsen".

Comment: SQL Server now has support for this too, Sequences is a superior solution to doing the same thing manually. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-sequence/