# Mysql Syntax PHP add the value of 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of a few songs with a few tables which are:

Database_table `playlist` with the following columns:

```
Song_timing
Song_title
Song_artist
Song_status
```

I want to be able add the value of 1 to the table `Song_status` (its either 0 or 1)

```
mysql_query("SELECT 'PLAYLIST' INSERT 1 INTO song_status WHERE song_timing like '$today%' GROUP BY song_title HAVING COUNT(song_title)>1");
```

The current syntax doesn't display an error at all it just doesn't work.

Comment: i think you need to check out MySQL INSERT queries first before trying to use it..!

Comment: You should take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9294062/2221315

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to increment integer Columns value by 1 in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293900/how-to-increment-integer-columns-value-by-1-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increment a value, then use `update` not `insert`.  Something like:

```
update play_list
    set song_status = song_status + 1
    where date(song_timing) = date(now())
```

Your attempted syntax is quite broken.  It should be returning some syntax error, probably on the `1` or the `into`.

Comment: How easy would it be to convert that into a PHP query?