# SQL Unmatched Data Types

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm getting an error when trying to increment a row in my db.

Here's the sql query.

```
var sql = "UPDATE USERS SET Submissions = CAST (Submissions AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST (1 AS VARCHAR(10)) WHERE Username="+userEmail;
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the type of submissions? Might it perhaps be an integer?

Comment: Please add the error text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294077/6121703

Answer (score 0):

If you're incrementing a row, you don't cast it to varchar(10).  You keep it as an integer:

```
var sql =
"UPDATE USERS 
    SET Submissions += 1
  WHERE Username="+userEmail;
```