# How to add numbers from mysql column to column and save database?

Tags: php, mysql

At two different tables,
The new value of [chargeINFO.u_chargewait]
I want to add and save the existing [userinfo.u_charged] value.
After the query operation, I want the value of [u_charged] to be saved as 150000.

[image]

I can't find it even if I search for the query statement.
Please help me. Thank you.

```
$query = "UPDATE userinfo
INNER JOIN chargeINFO ON (userinfo.u_id = chargeINFO.u_id)
SET userinfo.u_charged = chargeINFO.u_chargewait";
```

Comment: Rather than updating a single field to reflect the "current state" based on other information in the database it is generally far more advisable to do a JOIN and SUM in the query, or create a view that does it for you. Otherwise you're going to run into the issue of missed/malformed/interrupted queries not updating that "current state" field and it will no longer represent reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the result `150000` from the original `u_charged = 50000` and `u_chargewait = 100000`, you need to add the two columns together, rather than just assigning one to the other. Then you can assign the result back to the column to update it.

```
UPDATE userinfo
INNER JOIN chargeINFO ON (userinfo.u_id = chargeINFO.u_id)
SET userinfo.u_charged = userinfo.u_charged + chargeINFO.u_chargewait
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on the reasoning of yours? Perhaps by linking to existing Q&A material on site or writing an explanation?

Comment: @hakre I added some more details.

Comment: I dunno if in the spirit of the question the intention of asking is arithmetic simplicity rather than perhaps a reference how this answers the question. I bet you had something in mind when writing the answer. Perhaps you thought it's just a typo? Who am I to judge?

Comment: I suspect the OP assumed that SQL his syntax would automatically combine the columns rather than replacing. Beginning programmers frequently tend to think the computer can guess their intentions.

Comment: Well, that would be an interesting option for a database, auto ++updates. Wondering if ANSI SQL does not have something for it ... ;)

Comment: @hakre These are the same beginners who think you can write `if variable = 1 or 2 or 3`

Comment: I didn't want to trivialize it, this is just an example of a simple `column + 1` in SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293900/367456